# asp.net mvc url custom rewriting for seo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some new map routs but I want to change strings in url, for example in this mapping:

> mysite/News/More/13

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "IssueNews",
            url: "News/More/{newsId}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "News", 
                action = "More", 
                newsId = UrlParameter.Optional                
            }
        );
```

I want to use the title of news in my url and change it to this:

> mysite/News/{news title here}

any suggestion?

Comment: relevant question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248732/mvc-4-creating-slug-type-url/16252796

Answer (score 1):

This Route should be able to work

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IssueNewsTitle",
        url: "News/newsId/{newsTitle}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "News", 
            action = "More", 
            newsTitle= UrlParameter.Optional                
        }
    );
```

Comment: thanks, but my controller just get newsId. Should I take newsTitle in controller too?

Comment: so you want to use news title instead of news id in the controller, or you must use newsid to identify the news?

Comment: No I use news id to identify the news to show, but want to replace news title in url.

Comment: If this is the case you may want to consider redirect the action after the action and append only newstitle or newsid and newstitle to another actionresult