# how to remove the querystring parameters in url in mvc4 with razer using url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine, url.action, urlrewriting.net

url.action is :

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("CategoryLevel", "Product", new { CategoryId = @item._categoryId, ProductName = @Html.Raw(item._categoryName) })">@Html.Raw(item._categoryName)</a></li>
```

it works fine but i dont want to display the qyery string in url

url is:

`http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=16&ProductName=Common%20Conditions`

```
i want to display this as


`http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel/16/Common%20Conditions`  (or)`http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel/Common%20Conditions(or)http://localhost:99/Product/Common%20Conditions`
```

route config is:
            `routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "Home",
                       url: "{controller}/{action}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                   );`

ActionResult in controller is:`

```
public ActionResult CategoryLevel()
        {
            string ProductName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
            ViewBag.ProductName = ProductName;
            int Category = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]);
            ViewBag.ParentCategoryId = Category;
            int ParentCategoryId = 0;
            if (Request.QueryString["ParentCategoryId"] != null)
            {
                ParentCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ParentCategoryId"]);
            }
            Product productInstance = new Product();
            IList<CategoryInfo> categories = new List<CategoryInfo>();
            categories = productInstance.GetCategories(Category, true);
            if (categories.Count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("NewProducts", "Product", new { @CategoryId = Category,  ProductName = ProductName });
            }

            return View(categories);

        }`another actionresult is`public ActionResult NewProducts(Product instance)
        {
            string ProductName = Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
            instance.BrandName = ProductName;
            int CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]);
            int BrandId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["BrandId"]);
            string SortBy = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["sortBy"]);
            if (SortBy != null)
            {
                Session["Sort"] = SortBy;
            }
            Session["NewProductsBrandId"] = BrandId;
            instance.CategoryId = CategoryId;
            instance.BrandId = BrandId;
            instance.SortBy = SortBy;
            return View(instance);
        }`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Remove query string in action method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672843/asp-net-mvc-remove-query-string-in-action-method)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672843/asp-net-mvc-remove-query-string-in-action-method

Answer (score 2):

Here goes descriptive solution -

First you need to have proper route -

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetails",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{categoryid}/{productname}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel" }
);
```

Then you can have controller action defined in this way.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult CategoryLevel(string CategoryId, string ProductName)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Finally the link in this way -

```
@Html.ActionLink("sample","CategoryLevel", "Product", new { CategoryId = 1, ProductName = "Rami Vemula" }, null)
```

URL generated - **`http://localhost:5738/Product/CategoryLevel/1/Rami%20Vemula`**

And when you click on link, you will get values as shown below -

[image]

Comment: url is rewrited but it will not redirect to the next page

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

Use `Html.ActionLink` instead of `a`

```
 @Html.ActionLink("EditUser", "CategoryLevel", "Product", new { Id = m.ID }, new { @class = "hide" })
```

Or

```
<a href='CategoryLevel/@m.ID/@m.Name' >@m.Name</a>
```

Comment: it's also generates the link with query string right ?

Comment: @SivaRajini No it generate query like this `http://localhost:53897/Test/DYmanicControllerPage/2`

Comment: it generates the url as expects but it will not redirect to next page@Jaimin

Comment: Common%20Conditions how can i  display this as Common Conditions (or) Common+Conditions(or) Common-Conditions @ jaimon

Comment: @user3166404 i don't understand your comment.please elaborate.